# GAS not working on windows machine

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-apps-script, safari

I created an application using GAS and HTML service. It works on Safari and Chrome on mac, using different logins for a google apps account, but for the same accounts, it does not run on any of the browsers in windows machine.

Regards,
Arjun

Code to load the page

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log( Utilities.jsonStringify(e) );
  if (!e.parameter.page | e.parameter['page'] == 'index'){
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  return htmlOutput;
  }

  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate();
}
```

The page that is not loading

```
<style type="text/css">

#header {
height:100px;
background:Green;
font-size:300%;
color: Black;
align-content: centre;
}

body
{
    padding: 50px;
}

.animate
{
    transition: all 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.action-button
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;  
}

.blue
{
    background-color: #3498DB;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}

.red
{
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #BD3E31;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #BD3E31;
}

.green
{
    background-color: #82BF56;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}

.yellow
{
    background-color: #F2CF66;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #D1B358;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px #D1B358;
}

.action-button:active
{
    transform: translate(0px,5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

</style>

<!-- display header -->

<div id="header">Green Leaf Airconditioning Services LLC</div>

<!-- Set up the div for users only and not supervisors -->

<? var logged_user = getcurruser(); ?>

<label><?=logged_user?></label>

<div id='users'>

<p><?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=timesheet'> <input type='button' name='formload' value="Time Sheet" class="action-button animate blue"></a></p>
<p><?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=expclaim'> <input type='button' name='formload' value="Expense Claim" class="action-button animate blue"></a></p>
<p><?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=leaveapp'> <input type='button' name='formload' value="Leave Request" class="action-button animate blue"></a></p>
<p><?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=tktrequest'> <input type='button' name='formload' value="Ticket Request" class="action-button animate blue"></a></p>

</div>

<div id='status'>
<!-- some options will be increased later -->
<!-- <p><?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=timesheet'> <input type='button' name='formload' value="Time Sheet" class="action-button animate blue"></a></p> -->
<p><?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=expclaimstatus'> <input type='button' name='formload' value="Expense Claim Status" class="action-button animate blue"></a></p>
<p><?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=leavestatus'> <input type='button' name='formload' value="Leave Status" class="action-button animate blue"></a></p>
<p><?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=tktstatus'> <input type='button' name='formload' value="Ticket Status" class="action-button animate blue"></a></p>


</div>


<!-- show this when the user is also a supervisor -->

<div id='supervisors'>

</div>
```

It works on any browser on the mac but does not work on any browser in windows.

Comment: Could you provide more information? What error do you get?  Any screenshot or even the code you used

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! Now if you want some help, post code samples on it, console errors, more info, this give us nothing.

Comment: Hi, Problem is that I do not get any error. I just get a blank screen. It does not log any error.

Comment: Try to check if there is an error in the Chrome developer tools and if there is something add here the error or screen shot: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getScriptUrl is not defined. But the function is defined in code.gs file, which gets the current url of the project. it is

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getScriptUrl is not defined. But the function is defined in code.gs file, which gets the current url of the project. it is  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;

Comment: Another error I see now when i remove the reference to the code.gs function is Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "https://script.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://n-s4l3fceixqrfpges6wcd22mua3rch6p63aeg6wq-script.googleusercontent.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. 4118549896-maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js:260

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a test app, with as little code as possible in order to go through a process of elimination to debug what is wrong.  Create an index page with no styling; just one scriptlet; take the conditional check out of the `doGet()`; and reproduce the problem.  When you get it to work, start adding code and HTML back in a little at a time.  That's what we would need to do to get you an answer.

Comment: I did exactly as you told. The application works fine when I run it from drive.google.com, but when publishing the link I get the following error  Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "https://script.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://n-s4l3fceixqrfpges6wcd22mua3rch6p63aeg6wq-script.googleusercontent.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. in the google developer console

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  Do a search on that error message.